# Stored Procedures and Events Aurora via CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I use CloudFormation's [`AWS::RDS::DBCluster`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html) resource to create my Aurora MySQL database cluster.

My question is, has anyone created stored procedures as well as events in Aurora MySQL via CloudFormation? Is that even possible?

Delivering these via CloudFormation would allow me to recreate the infrastructure without deploying the stored procedures and events separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to configure stored procedures and events with the [`AWS::RDS::DBCluster`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html) CloudFormation resource directly.

My suggestion would be to provision an [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) containing a [`UserData`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) script that installs the mysql client, then executes the contents of a user-provided MySQL script creating events/stored-procedures on the newly-created DB instance.

Comment: thanks @wjordan, that gave me some ideas on how to start working on this one, I have also check out some sample templates (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-us-west-2.html) and particularly this one that installs the WordPress database https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/WordPress_Single_Instance.template